# Temporaries, references and ternary operator in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I've got the following base code:

```
struct X {
  X(const char* descr) {...}
  ~X() {...} // Not virtual
  virtual void foo() const {...}
};

struct Y : public X {
  Y(const char* descr) {...}
  ~Y() {...} // Not virtual
  virtual void foo() const {...}
};


const X& factory() {
    static X sampleX{"staticX"};
    static Y sampleY{"staticY"};
    return X or Y depending of the test case;
};
```

And 4 test cases:

**Just `Y`** = OK

```
const X& var = Y{"temporaryY"};
var.foo();
```

Result:

```
X::X() // base temporaryY
Y::Y() // temporaryY
Y::foo()
Y::~Y() // temporaryY
X::~X() // base temporaryY
```

**Just `X`** = OK

```
const X& var = X{"temporaryX"};
var.foo();
```

Result:

```
X::X() // temporaryX
X::foo()
X::~X() // temporaryX
```

**`Y` or `X` via function** = OK

```
const X& var = factory();
var.foo();
```

Result:

```
X::X() // staticX
X::X() // base staticY
Y::Y() // staticY
X::foo() or Y::foo()
Y::~Y() // staticY
X::~X() // base staticY
X::~X() // staticX
```

**`Y` or `X` via ternary operator** = WTF?!

```
const X& var = false ? X{"temporaryX"} : Y{"temporaryY"};
var.foo();
```

Result:

```
X::X() // base temporaryY
Y::Y() // temporaryY
Y::~Y() // temporaryY
X::~X() // base temporaryY
X::foo()
X::~X() // base temporaryY
```

Could someone explain me why for the seven hells:

- Destructor of `Y` is called before end of the scope?
- `X::foo()` was called instead of `Y::foo()`?
- Destructor of `X` is run twice?

Comment: 1)Y is created,hence it has to be destructed. 3) ~X() is called once for X and another for Y objects. 2) because the object is X?

Comment: @us2012 Yes, it is not, hence the question mark. What we see in Q are bits and pieces, and the problem is obviously elsewhere.

Comment: @BЈовић Hmm. I had just removed my earlier comment (claiming that it couldn't be slicing) after the answers below made it plausible that it could be slicing?! I am really quite interested in how this turns out.

Comment: Note that your factory is somewhat misleading since it uses static instances, so the destructor happens not at the end of the scope of `var` but after `main` exits.

Comment: @Jarod42 It was just an example to show that a reference coming from a function is treated differently.

Comment: So, I'm right, the other example takes reference to temp value, whereas in your function example, you take reference to named value. Look what happens if your factory returns `*new Y` (memleak), or if you have 'Y factory_Y()' (this one acts as your other examples: ref to temp value). Your factory example works as 'Y y{namedY}; const X& var = y;' (`var` is not destructed, `y` does).

Comment: Other Note: it may be useful to track also copy/move constructor/assign. this way you would see the copy in the ternary op.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're missing is that your temporary `Y` is getting copy-constructed-by-slice into a hidden temporary `X` that's bound to your const reference. *That* is then the final destructor you see and also explains why the `Y` is destructed earlier than expected. The reason this copy is made is that the "return" from the ternary operator is only one type. An `X` can't possibly ever be treated as a `Y` so `X` is the common type to be used, thus inducing the extra temporary `X` object.

Note that this is different from the "Just Y" test case, because in that instance a `Y` temporary is created and then immediately attempts to bind to a `const X&` which is allowed. In the ternary case, the operator itself induces an intermediate slice to the common object type of the operators operands, in this case `X`.

I *believe* you can avoid the temporary slice by casting to parent reference but I don't have access to a C++11 compiler to test this (in addition to the somewhat incomplete code in the question):

```
const X& var = false ? X{"temporaryX"} : static_cast<const X&>(Y{"temporaryY"});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why slicing happens here, while it doesn't happen for OP's "just `Y`" test case? Is it because there's another level of subexpressions due to the conditional operator?

Comment: @us2012 Look at *5.16/3* of the n3690 standard draft.

Comment: Just so that noone has to reopen his copy of standard: "if E1 and E2 have class type, and the underlying class types are the same or **one is a base class of the other**: E1 can be converted to match E2 if the class of T2 is the same type as, or a base class of, the class of T1, (...). If the conversion is applied, **E1 is changed to a prvalue of type T2 by copy-initializing a temporary of type T2** from E1 and using that temporary as the converted operand."

Answer (score 5):

> Destructor of Y is called before end of the scope?

Because an object of type `Y` is created then it has to be destroyed. Because it is a temporary object, it has to be destroyed at the end of the expression (after the `;`).

> X::foo() was called instead of Y::foo()?

Because of [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) it calls the `X:foo` method. The object is sliced into a temporary `X` object.

*This is explained in the standard at §5.16/3.*

> Destructor of X is run twice?

The `X` destructor is called once for the `Y` temporary object and once for `var`.

---